# Does Allah forgive every sin?

Tags: allah, sin

There are different kind of sins, but if you repent honestly then Allah will forgive you, right?

Still, are there any sins that Allah will never forgive?

Answer (score 10):

Allah says:

> Indeed, Allah does not forgive association with Him, but He forgives what is less than that for whom He wills. And he who associates others with Allah has certainly fabricated a tremendous sin. (Quran 4:48)

So everything is forgivable by Allah, except Shirk (association of others with Allah in worship). Thus, by being Muslim, everything is forgivable by Allah will. Shirk and Kufur are alike. ([Source](http://www.qsep.com/modules.php?name=ilm&d_op=article&sid=888))

Edit:

Just for clarification, even Shirk (association) or Kufur (denying Allah) are still forgivable as long as one has repented before dying.

Comment: This passage reads to me as "Allah does not forgive association [*of oneself*] with Him...".  Association *of others* with Him is mentioned separately...seemingly as a forgivable, if still "tremendous", sin.  Were it not, there'd be no point in becoming a Muslim, or in coming back to Islam -- one would already be condemned.

Comment: @cHao The verse talks about association in general, regardless of associating oneself or others, which both is still considered association (see http://quran.com/4/48 for more different English translations.) One note that I might not have clarified is that association is still forgivable by Allah for whomsoever as long as one has repented before dying.

Comment: Forgivable, yes.  Surely, an all-powerful being can forgive whatever he wants to.  But "Allah does not forgive" seems to make it pretty clear that he has no will to do so, and "If you repent, Allah forgives" would seem to fly in the face of that.  How do they reconcile?

Comment: @cHao Allah forgives Shirk and Kufur when someone repents from them before dying. When it comes to others sins without repentance, everyone is at the mercy of Allah to whatever He wishes, either to punish or to forgive. Even a Muslim can't say that he/she will succeed just because he/she worships Allah properly. It is not a contract. For more: http://www.call-to-monotheism.com/does_allah_forgive_shirk___by_ansar_al__adl

Answer (score 6):

You are correct when you say that there are some sins that Allah doesn't forgive. And that is Shirk(ascribing partners with Allah)

> Indeed, Allah does not forgive association with Him, but He forgives
>   what is less than that for whom He wills. And he who associates others
>   with Allah has certainly fabricated a tremendous sin. (Quran 4:48)

This would only apply in the case where a person died without asking forgiveness for committing shirk. Because if you look at the tafsir of the above verse it says

> { إن الله لا يغفر أن يُشرك } أي الإشراك { به ويغفر ما دون } سوى { ذلك
>   } من الذنوب { لمن يشاء } المغفرة له بأن يدخله الجنة بلا عذاب ومن شاء
>   عذّبه من المؤمنين بذنوبه ثم يدخله الجنة { ومن يشرك بالله فقد افترى
>   إثما } ذنبا { عظيما } كبيرا .
>   Source: [Jalalain](http://quran.com/4/48)

It means the Allah can forgive all sins except shirk and by forgiveness means entering into Jannah without being punished.

To receive forgiveness from God regardless of any sin there are three requirements:

- >  Recognizing the offense itself and its admission before God.
- >     Making a commitment not to repeat the offense.
- >     Asking for forgiveness from God.

Source: http://southernmuslimah.wordpress.com/2007/10/06/very-beautiful-hadith-and-forgiveness-in-islam/

The verses below depict the forgiveness of Allah and his mercy if we sincerely repent
Allah says in Surah Zumar 39:53

> Say, "O My servants who have transgressed against themselves [by
>   sinning], do not despair of the mercy of Allah . Indeed, Allah
>   forgives all sins. Indeed, it is He who is the Forgiving, the
>   Merciful."

On the authority of Anas, who said: I heard the messenger of Allah say:

> Allah the Almighty has said: “O son of Adam, so long as you call upon
>   Me and ask of Me, I shall forgive you for what you have done, and I
>   shall not mind. O son of Adam, were your sins to reach the clouds of
>   the sky and were you then to ask forgiveness of Me, I would forgive
>   you. O son of Adam, were you to come to Me with sins nearly as great
>   as the earth and were you then to face Me, **ascribing no partner to Me**,
>   I would bring you forgiveness nearly as great as its.”

Answer (score -3):

No, Allah will forgive his creation, for every kind of sin he has commited!

And as my friend Ghasan has qouted a Holy Verse:

> Indeed, Allah does not forgive association with Him, but He forgives what is less than that for whom He wills. And he who associates others with Allah has certainly fabricated a tremendous sin. (Quran 4:48)

I would like to add some particular words here just to elaborate what Allah really means here.

First of all, no man on this planet except of the Prophets are able to understand what Allah means to say and what he actually wants us to do. We people are sinners, we cannot get the main idea of what Allah is.

He will forgive every sin committed by a man on Earth when he will kneel before Him and will apologize by his heart. Now lets take the example of the People of Meccah, they abused Holy Prophet (PBUH) in every manner, they hurted him, yet, when they became Muslims; notable personalities:

1. Abu Sufe'yan. The noble person of the Meccah, who was an infidel, but when Meccah was conquered, his house was declared as a place where infidels can live at peace without being harmed or attacked at!

Now you might want to know, why I said, Allah would forgive a person who has have been an infidel, its because Allah gives everyone a chance to ask for apology. Allah will forgive us for being infidel.

The Verse means here that Allah will never forgive a person after his death. Until his life, he can turn to Allah.

And that is exactly what is meant by the qoute:

> Turn to Allah, before you return to Allah.

The other sins are minors, such as Drinking, Smoking (although I hate smoking so I am adding it here; and also to be noted anything drug is prohibited in Islam, even its small quantity), Sex, Cheating etc. They are forgiven by Allah at the very time when his man apologizes for it.

Allah would never punish his creation. And he is thus known as **Rehman** and **Rahim**.

Answer (score -5):

God forgives all of our sins except those sins that relate to people and don't pertain to to God.

*E.g.:*

God won't forgive killing and oppressing people because human rights are very important in Islam.

Comment: Life is complicated because is killing out of self defence ok? E.G during the war. The one who kills , a military man, is accountable for the killing of another human being but what about the superiors/ the leaders are they not responsible.