# Is it wrong for a Muslim to say that no Hindus will go to Jannah?

Tags: jannah, other-religions, akhirah, hindu

Many Muslim preachers say that Hindus will not enter Jannah because they are idol worshipers. But why would they say something like that? Who goes to Jannah and who goes to Jahannam is Allah's choice. Allah might be merciful towards particular Hindu individuals and allow them to enter Jannah. We can never know who will enter Jannah. It all depends on what Allah wants. We don't know the future. Only Allah does.

Is it wrong for a Muslim to say that no Hindus will go to Jannah?

Comment: Related Answer: http://islam.stackexchange.com/a/11587/3259

Answer (score 1):

Yes brother it is true as Muslims we should not claim to know the unseen as that is beyond us and Allah's domain, although Allah has reviled the glorious Quran and in it he has stated that the only religion acceptable in the eyes of Allah is Islam. This is the motivation that Scholars use to back such statements.

Further more it is clearly stated in the Quran that idol worship is Haraam and a great injustices.

As far as those who will enter Jannah and Jhanam Allahu Alim(Allah knows best)!

References:

Quran: 
al-Imran [3:19]
Indeed, the religion in the sight of Allah is Islam. And those who were given the Scripture did not differ except after knowledge had come to them - out of jealous animosity between themselves. And whoever disbelieves in the verses of Allah , then indeed, Allah is swift in [taking] account.

[31:13] Recall that Luqmaan said to his son, as he enlightened him, "O my son, do not set up any idols beside Allah; idolatry is a gross injustice."

[4:48] Allah does not forgive idolatry,* but He forgives lesser offenses for whomever He wills. Anyone who sets up idols beside Allah, has forged a horrendous offense.

[4:116] Allah does not forgive idol worship (if maintained until death),* and He forgives lesser offenses for whomever He wills. Anyone who idolizes any idol beside Allah has strayed far astray.

[39:65] It has been revealed to you, and to those before you that if you ever commit idol worship, all your works will be nullified, and you will be with the losers.(Those of the hellfire)

Comment: Yes but Allah knows what we don't know. So it should be safe to say that Allah may grant Jannah to those we least expect to enter Jannah.

Comment: The Qurash believed in Allah but they believed that they had to worship Allah through idols. This is the reason some of these iyayt were relieved, so they and those like them turn to Allah alone and repent in order to achieve Jannah.

Comment: I agree with your mind set unless it goes against the Sahih Hadith or words of  Allah ie: Quran [4:116] Allah does not forgive idol worship....
Allah is perfect with out flaws and if he were to go against his own words that would diminish the perfection of Allah.If we believed that Allah was flawed then we would surly be in error and perhaps fall outside the fold of Islam . 
Allah knows best !
 You are welcome to disagree but please support your statment with the Quran and/or Sahih Hadith.