# Is there a way I could be forgiven if I intentionally eat non halal meat

Tags: halal-haram, shiism, forgiveness, meat

At the age of 16 I had this one friend in which we both didn't really think about our religion. One night we were at her house and we ordered food from a place that wasn't halal and I'm not saying it was her fault because I was fully aware of my actions and I knew it was haram yet I still did it but I sorta felt as if it was peer pressure from both of us. A year has passed now and I've basically lost contact with her but I've been giving that day a thought and I've never ate unhalal meat again but I regret that day so much and wonder if I'm gonna be punished for it even though I wasn't that aware of the punishments of doing haram things. Also I wanna know if there is a way that I could ask for forgiveness about that specific reason. Any sort of help is accepted thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The answer to "Is it possible to be forgiven for [blah] by Allah?" is going to be "Yes." See [Does Allah forgive every sin?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/11584/17163)

> He who seeks repentance (from the Lord) before the rising of the sun from the west (before the Day of Resurrection), Allah turns to him with Mercy.
>   <sub>[Sahih Muslim 2703](https://sunnah.com/muslim/48/55)</sub>

But the decision is up to Allah:

> Indeed, Allah does not forgive association with Him, but He forgives what is less than that for whom He wills. And he who associates others with Allah has certainly fabricated a tremendous sin.
>   <sub>[Qur'an 4:48](https://quran.com/4/48)</sub>

Two of [Allah's names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Names_of_God_in_Islam) are The Repeatedly Forgiving and The Much-Forgiving, so we can expect that He will forgive generously.  To this end, the process of repentance is described here: [How does one repent in Islam?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/8151/17163)

Answer (score 0):

Salam. ask forgiveness of Allah and try your best efforts that dont repeate this mistake. Allah is the most forgiving, the most merciful.

Amirul-Mu'minin (a) said to the man who was prevailed by despair of God’s mercy out of his many sins: “You, to despair of the mercy of Allah is the greatest sin that you have ever committed.”
Quoted from Jami us-Sa’adat; part 1 page 246.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a way I can be forgiven if I intentionally eat unholy meat?
If someone knows that this meat is forbidden and this food is forbidden, that is, he knows both the food (the subject) and the ruling that it is forbidden, yet he eats it, commits a mistake and disobeys, and this act is rebellion and disobedience. It is considered one of the divine commands and deserves its special punishment and punishment. And this sin has bad effects on human life.
Imam Sadegh (AS) says about the evil effects of sin: The effect of sin is that it deprives man of worship. Sometimes a person is afflicted with a sin during the day and as a result he is deprived of night life and night prayer. Unless he repents and corrects his past.

Ref: https://www.islamquest.net/fa/archive/fa1431